# Can I share the Wi-Fi connection of my Mac to the internet with my iPad?

Tags: ipad, mac, usb, internet

My Mac is connected to the internet via Wi-Fi.

Can I use this connection for my iPad? I guess creating a local network is not possible, since I already use the wifi of the mac. So, is it possible by connecting the iPad with the USB cable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To share your Mac internet connection with your iPad do the following ([Source with some screenshots](http://www.idownloadblog.com/2014/01/19/how-to-share-your-macbook-wi-fi-connection-with-your-ipad/))

1. On your Mac, go to Apple > System Preferences > Bluetooth > Turn Bluetooth On.
2. Turn Bluetooth On on your iPad.
3. Your iPad should show up as a new device in the Bluetooth preferences of your Mac. Click Pair. A six digit number will appear on your Mac. This same number should show up on your iPad. Confirm the connection by tapping “Pair” on your iPad.
4. On your Mac, go to Apple > System Preferences > Sharing

   - Click on “Internet Sharing” from the menu on the left. Do not check the box yet!
   - Select: Share your connection from “Wi-Fi”
   - Check: To computers using “Bluetooth PAN”
   - Check the “Internet Sharing” box from the menu on the left
   - When asked if you’re sure you want to share your connection, select “Start”
     share mac internet with iPad

At this point, you should be able to get online on your iPad. Obviously, for this to work, your Mac will have to be awake and connected to the internet.

Comment: To connect with the iPad, I had to go the preferences of the iPad.